# Imported my car from NZ to Sydney(AU) and doesn’t start after a short journey on hot days unless I wait for half an hour or so to let it cool down?

Tags: starting, mitsubishi, eclipse

I’ve imported my Mitsubishi eclipse cross 2018 from New Zealand in January 2023 when I moved to Sydney Australia. It took 3 months to get it due to some delays on import permits.
Now problem is, on hot day if I drive it for about 30minutes or longer and turn it off when I try to start it again it just cranks but doesn’t start, I have to wait for another 30 to 40minutes to let it cool and then it starts like normal.
Mitsubishi Australia is saying it could be fuel pump issue, I’m not expert but I think it has to do with hot weather otherwise shouldn’t start when it cools down. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a total newbie but I have heard of something similar happening to a Volkswagen vehicle imported from Germany to Greece. The problem was that the German edition had a few covers in the front of the cover that prevented its cooling and summers in Greece are quite harsh so the engine overheated. It might be a long shot but I would check if your vehicle had any differences with vehicles sold in warmer climates in terms of covers etc. Good luck with your issue!

Comment: Maybe so, but Sydney's climate isn't any hotter than New Zealand's.  Darwin's might be.

Answer (score 0):

What are the ambient temperatures?  How does the temperature gauge "normal" point compare between driving it in NZ and now in AU?

Its clearly heat-related - but not enough to make the engine physically hard to turn (like tight rings)

Are you using the same fuels that you used in New Zealand?  NZ has 91 and 95 octane, and the [manual for your car](https://mitsubishi-motors.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/18.5MY-Eclipse-Cross-Owners-Manual.pdf) says:

> Fuel requirements:   Unleaded petrol octane number 95 RON or higher

Suggestions:

1. Try opening the bonnet/hood and seeing what's hotter than normal.  (don't burn yourself)
2. Confirm you're using 95 octane fuel
3. Check/clean/replace any fuel filters and air filters - they may be choked up.

Otherwise get your garage to check for codes with their scan tools.

Comment: I was tempted to suggest spraying or misting liquid water onto different parts of the engine when its not-starting.  To try and identify what area needs to cool down to start.   But there's a risk of shock-cooling and breaking something, which might not even be the cause of the initial problem.  I would do it on my own car, but not actively suggest this as a diagnosis technique for you.